# Profile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user' while extending django's User model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-users

Here I have extended django's user model with profile model and i want to add this fields to user model.
Following are the files.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Profile(models.Model):
    user_ref = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pr1_points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pr2_points = models.IntegerField(default=0)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    user = instance
    if created:
        profile = Profile(user=user)
        profile.save() 

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**register function in views.py is as follows :**

'''

```
def postregister(request):

if request.POST:
    first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
    last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
    password2 = request.POST.get('password2')
    
    if password1 == password2:
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'Username is Taken Please Try Again')
            return render(request,'signup.html')
        elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'Email is Taken Please Try Again')
            return render(request,'signup.html')
        else:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, password=password1)
            user.save()
            print('You are registered successfully, Please sign to continue.')
            return redirect('login')
            
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Password is not matching Please Try Again')
        return render(request,'signup.html')
else:
    return redirect('register')
```

'''

so while creating new user it is giving error as: **Profile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'.**
SO please anyone know the answer help me with this.

Here's the screenshot of error for reference
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qE4q.png

Comment: you have `user_ref` in Profile right...?? Please confirm it should be `profile = Profile(user_ref=user)` or `profile = Profile(user=user)`...

Comment: It worked @ShivendraPratapKushwaha Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `user_ref` in `Profile` model.

Replace

```
profile = Profile(user=user)
```

with

```
profile = Profile(user_ref=user)
```